# Diagonal Grid Traverse in Python

Tags: python, matrix, traversal

**Edited for clarity**

I've searched everywhere for this but havent found anything. I would like to traverse a 2D list of strings and display the slices like they do here **[Traverse 2D Array (Matrix) Diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862802/traverse-2d-array-matrix-diagonally)** but in python.

```
lines = ['xmfycxvc',
         'caubmekv',
         'awactivb',
         'paphzkcn',
         'sbsaakjy',
         'tsewlhvk']
diagonals = []
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
   j = 0
   diagonal = ''
   while j < len(lines[0]):
      diagonal += lines[j][j]
      i += 1
diagonals.append(diagonal)
print(diagonals)
```

I know my indexes are wrong but i've tried everything and still cant make it like the link. the closest I've come is to have every diagonal but the would also wrap around the matrix like a sphere like this `['xaahah','muczkv','fbtkjk','cevnss','xkbpbs','vvaasw','xxwpal']` but I dont want that.

I want to traverse diagonally through the matrix of strings and print the diagonals e.g. `['x','cm','aaf','pwuy','saabc','tbpcmx','sshtev','eazikc','wakvv','lkcb','hjn','vy','k']` and their counter parts going from top-left -> botom-right.

Comment: I answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603278/how-to-iterate-the-cartesian-product-so-top-items-combine-first/32603848#32603848

Comment: After your edit it is clear that your data is not a 2D array of strings but rather a list of strings of equal length... fortunately for me my answer below still works perfectly.  If you want to present your results as a list of strings it can be done really easy but in your first edit you just referred to printing the diagonals,

Comment: I'm actually looking to store the diagonals in a list so i can search for words in the diagonals. I'm looking at your response now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a bit of reasoning we have that for each diagonal in a matrix the difference between the column number (or `x` in what follows) and the row number (`y`) is constant.  We can use as our data structure a `collections.defaultdict` that is autoinitialised as an empty list and have a loop on all the matrix elements, finding the diagonal to which each element belongs and listing those elements in our `defaultdict`.

```
def getdiags(matrix, nr, nc):
    from collections import defaultdict
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for y in range(nr):
        for x in range(nc):
            d[x-y].append(matrix[y][x])
    return d
```

We can profit also from an utility function to present in order our results

```
def printdiags(diags):
    for i in sorted(diags):
        print diags[i]
```

Finally we test our things in IPython

```
In [1]: def getdiags(matrix, nr, nc):
        from collections import defaultdict
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for y in range(nr):
                for x in range(nc):
                        d[x-y].append(matrix[y][x])
        return d
   ...:     

In [2]: def printdiags(diags):
        for i in sorted(diags):
                print diags[i]
   ...:         

In [3]: from pprint import pprint

In [4]: m = [["%3.3d"%(r*100+c)  for c in range(5)] for r in range(4)]

In [5]: pprint(m)
[['000', '001', '002', '003', '004'],
 ['100', '101', '102', '103', '104'],
 ['200', '201', '202', '203', '204'],
 ['300', '301', '302', '303', '304']]

In [6]: diags = getdiags(m, 4, 5)

In [7]: printdiags(diags)
['300']
['200', '301']
['100', '201', '302']
['000', '101', '202', '303']
['001', '102', '203', '304']
['002', '103', '204']
['003', '104']
['004']

In [8]:
```

<strike>That's all</strike>

#### Addendum

In a late edit, the OP stated that their input is a list of strings of equal length and that the answer is seeked in terms of a list of diagonals.

My `getdiags` above works as well with the new alternative data structure and obtaining the seeked list is very simple:

```
def listofdiags(diags):
    return [''.join(diags[i]) for i in sorted(diags)]
```

Of course this conversion can be implemented also *inside* `getdiagonals` but that is left as an exercise.

#### Look, no `defaultdict`

```
# List of Strings from Diagonals
def lsd(m, nr, nc):
    res = ["" for i in range(nr+nc-1)]
    for r in range(nr):
        for c in range(nc):
            i = c-r+nr-1
            res[i] = res[i]+m[r][c]
    return res

pprint(lsd(m, 4, 5))
# ['300',
#  '200301',
#  '100201302',
#  '000101202303',
#  '001102203304',
#  '002103204',
#  '003104',
#  '004']
```

#### `yield`ing the solution

The following is less efficient but for the sake of completeness, here it is:

```
def enumdiags(m, nr, nc):
    for i in range(nr+nc-1):
        s = ""
        for r in range(nr):
            for c in range(nc):
                if c-r+nr-1 == i : s = s+m[r][c]
        yield i, s

for i, s in enumdiags(m, 4, 5):
    print i, s
# 0 300
# 1 200301
# 2 100201302
# 3 000101202303
# 4 001102203304
# 5 002103204
# 6 003104
# 7 004
```

Comment: used the one without the defaultDict as it was more easier for me to understand its function. thanks for your answer and extensive explanation

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** to reduce complexity

```
    def printer(matrix, i, j, listOfDiagonals):
        if i + 1 > len(matrix) or j + 1 > len(matrix[0]):
            return listOfDiagonals
        else:
            listOfDiagonals.append(matrix[i][j])
            printer(matrix, i+1, j+1, listOfDiagonals)

    matrix = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
    for i in matrix:
        print i
    list = []
    printer(matrix, 0, 0, list)
    print list
```

Where matrix is your matrix and then `i` and `j` are your indexes.

This will recursively add content at the index location to a list that is eventually returned when the boundaries of the matrix are reached. The good thing about this design is that the matrix doesn't need to be square for it to still traverse the diagonal.

Comment: I don't think it will be easy for a beginner to understand how this works. I suggest giving a bit of explanation and showing an example of how to use it (what `i` and `j` value should you call your function with etc... or create a "wrapper" that just takes the matrix as only argument and fills automatically the other parameters to your `printer` function)

Comment: @JulienBernu sorry! This is the first time I've posted an answer

Comment: I already made a wrapper function and inside i call the recursive. i started with i and j as 0, and provided `x = len(lines[0]` and `y = len(lines)`. i am trying it out atm.

Comment: well, I'm having a small complication, my wrapper function takes in 1 argument but the recursive takes in 6 and its coming up as an error. any thoughts?

Comment: @TheOneNeo I edited it to remove the x and y variables. Can you post your wrapper code?

Comment: @Aginor i found the problem i had. i was calling the wrapper within the recursive. now that i fixed that the recursive return none

Comment: the grid is this:

    `grid = ['xmfycxvc', 
                 'caubmekv', 
                 'awactivb', 
                 'paphzkcn', 
                 'sbsaakjy', 
                 'tsewlhvk']`

Comment: Ahhhhh, so the list parameter is passed by reference. The following should give you what you want:

`
list = []

printer(matrix, 0, 0, list)
print list
`

Comment: `def Diagonals(grid,i,j,listofdiagonals):
     if i + 1 > len(lines) or j + 1 > len(lines[0]):
         return
      else:
         listofdiagonals.append(lines[i][j])`

just returns one diagonal not all of them

Comment: I've edited the orignal question to make it more clear what i need. sorry for that.